# fancybox.update() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, fancybox

I have a fancybox to manage users. Now I defined a function to set a user to primary. Here is the template:

```
<ul class="user-list">
    {{#each inquiry.users as |user|}}
        <li>
          {{user.email}}
          {{#if (isEqual user.id createdBy)}}<span> (primary) </span> 
              {{else}} <button type="button" class="pretty small btn" {{action 'setPrimary' user}}>Set to Primary</button>
           {{/if}}
          <div class="pretty small danger btn icon-right entypo icon-cancel" {{action 'removeUser' user}}><a href="#">remove</a></div>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is the controller:

```
createdBy: function() {
    return this.get('inquiry.created_by');
}.property('inquiry'),
actions: {
    setPrimary: function(user){
        var inquiry = this.get('inquiry');
        var userId = user.get('id');
        inquiry.set('created_by', userId);
        inquiry.save();
        $.fancybox.update();
    }
}
```

You see that createdBy in the isEqual helper is a computed property. If the user's id is equal to inquiry's created person's id, the user is the primary user. Or you can set the user as the primary user, which trigger an action to set the `created_by` of inquiry to the current user's id. I used the `$.fancybox.update()` to re-render the content, but when I click the `Set as Primary` button nothing changed. Could someone tell me which part is wrong? Should I use observer instead of computed property for `createdBy` property?

Comment: What the `$.fancybox.update` method does is `Auto-sizes fancyBox height to match height of content ` ... so the question is: does your content actually changes when you press the `Set as Primary` button? (assuming that this button is part of the content of an already opened fancybox) ... or shoukd I ask, do you really understand what does the `$.fancybox.update` method do? (which is not to re-render the content or whatsoever)

Comment: Hi JFK, thanks for helping me clear the usage of `$.fancybox.update`. I was assuming that it will re-render the content. Ok, this is the reason why I have to refresh the page to see the changes. You know how to solve this issue? Any ideas would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: I finally solved this issue by adding an observer the computed property `createdBy` and whichever user you click to set as primary the result shows immediately. 

    `createdByChanged: function(){
        this.set('createdBy', this.get('inquiry.created_by'));
    }.observes('inquiry.created_by')`